# Tab Bar Controllers Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I currently have an issue with my project. It consists of two tab bar controllers, each of them has 4 tabs and thus 4 navigation paths. There is a button on the first tab bar controller to go to the 4th tab on the second tab bar controller. This works fine, but then when I click on a button on the second tab bar controller, I get this issue in console:

`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for`

When I try to switch back to the first tab bar controller, I get the same issue.

Does anyone have experience with this and can help me?

Comment: Can you show how you're navigating to the other tab bar controller?

Comment: In my `prepareForSegue`, I have  

`let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! RenterTabBarController` and

`tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3`